# ubuntu 14.04 Gnome classic desktop

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts, gnome-classic

I want to create shortcuts on desktop and panels. Installation is Ubuntu Gnome 14.4 with classic desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on any icon in the file browser, you'll see a 'Make Link' option. That is the equivalent of 'Create Shortcut' on windows.

If you want to create a link for a program on the desktop or the panel, you can drag and drop it from the applications menu to either one.

The top panel (or wherever you put it) has several types of options you could use for different types of tasks. The easy way is to drag any files you want quick access to, and drop them on the panel.

If you right click on the panel while holding 'super+alt' buttons, you will see a drop down menu with several options to edit the panel or to create additional panels.